# Is there something similar to UIModeManager.setCurrentModeType()?

Tags: android, android-tv

I am working in an application for normal smartphones and I am creating new layouts for Android TV (using only a dpad).

The device that I use to try the layout, seems not to be an "official" television. Indeed the tag "television"

television: Device is displaying on a television, providing a "ten foot" experience where its UI is on a large screen that the user is far away from, primarily oriented around DPAD or other non-pointer interaction

does not work and also the example

```
public static final String TAG = "DeviceTypeRuntimeCheck";

UiModeManager uiModeManager = (UiModeManager) getSystemService(UI_MODE_SERVICE);
if (uiModeManager.getCurrentModeType() == Configuration.UI_MODE_TYPE_TELEVISION) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Running on a TV Device")
} else {
    Log.d(TAG, "Running on a non-TV Device")
}
```

taken from [here](https://developer.android.com/training/tv/start/hardware.html) gives me the result "Running on a non-TV device".

Well, right now I am solving the problem creating layouts using the tag "notouch", but I would like to force my "non official" TV to behavies as a TV. I was thinking in something similar to

```
uiModeManager.setCurrentModeType(Configuration.UI_MODE_TYPE_TELEVISION)
```

but in the offical documentation of UiModeManager it seems this method does not exist.

Is there some option to force a device to act as a television and not using the workaround with "notouch"?

I know that maybe most of you will suggest "not" to change the default settings of a device, but also for curiosity, could it be possible? Can you force Android to use, for example, the "small" tag with large screen size or something like this? I know that it could be possible (even if not suggested) with language, but for the screen?